# PHP5-FPM refuses to log errors running under Foreman nginx with Heroku buildpack

Tags: heroku, nginx, vagrant, php, foreman

I have tried absolutely everything for days now, and there is no way I can get PHP to log its errors locally or running on Heroku itself.  My exact setup:

**VAGRANT BOX:** Homestead/laravel (this contains the PHP / Nginx install)
Once the vagrant box is running, I stop the running services (`sudo service nginx stop` and `sudo service php5-fpm stop`).  The Heroku toolbelt is installed on this box.  I am using PHP Version 5.6.0-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, but have tried with previous versions (different version of Homestead/Laravel box).

**COMPOSER INSTALL:** I have the following composer.json file, although I have tried various options including not using my own buildpack but just the default one etc.

```
{
"extra": {
    "heroku": {
        "document-root": "webroot",
        "index-document": "index.php"
    }
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/ashleycoker/heroku-buildpack-php"
    }
],
"require-dev": {
    "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "dev-master"
}
```

}

**FOREMAN:** I run my own procfile using `sudo foreman start -f Procfile.dev` shown here:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -v webroot/
```

Everything works as expected, apart from the error logging for PHP.  I am actually running an expressionengine install, and can access PHPinfo fine and see that the error log is set to `/tmp/heroku.php-fpm.www.5000.log`.  log_errors is on, and everything you would expect seems fine in the ini file.

I think I have read / tried every solution on Google to get this to work but to no avail.  I have tried changing the ownership of the error_log file, changing its location, changing PHP error log settings including to have E_ALL so everything is logged.  I even get the PHP notices on the screen so I know something should be going into the log file.

An important line from heroku-php-nginx that seems important is the fact that it redirects all logs to stderr so that Heroku can pick them up - exactly what I want to happen.

```
( touch "${logs[@]}"; tail -qF -n 0 "${logs[@]}" | strip_fpm_child_said 1>&2 || true; echo 'tail "${logs[@]}"' >&3; ) 3> $wait_pipe &
```

However I can not see the logs anywhere!

I just want errors to be logged so that I can go into production with some peace of mind!

Any more info required just ask and I will happily answer ASAP with as much info as I can.

Thanks